# Exception in DalvikVM: No free temp registers

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to develop a mobile application android using PhoneGap and jquery mobile. The application runs normal until a stage that displays me the following error:

```
 No free temp registers 
 Jit: aborting trace compilation, reverting to interpreter
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is it causing any problem in your app? it looks like a harmless warning.. check out following thread for more detail.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936758/android-exception-in-dalvikvm

Comment: but my application does not show any problem. it runs well but at a certain stage he displays this error

Comment: if it does not effect your app then dont worry about that.. it would be some android internal bug that would be fixed in future... or its just and debug message... check the link I have posted in my comment.. the is already a issue filed for it... at the following link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18647